# Save and load background with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code I have on my website: you can see a `select` with a dropdown list that has a few options. When an option is clicked, a background will be loaded with the `onchange()` event.

```
<select id="rds" onchange="bg(this[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="0.png">1. Default</option>
    <option value="1.png">2. Collage</option>
    <option value="2.jpg">3. Darkness</option>
</select>
```

And here the `bg()` function:

```
function bg(num) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/" + num + ")";
}
```

This works perfectly. I have to save the option that an user selected, so every time he opens the webpage, he can see the background he selected.

I was thinking to save a `cookie` and load it. Since I saw that it's a bit tricky with javascript, I thought I could use `jQuery` and so I made this:

```
<select id="rds" onchange="bg(this[this.selectedIndex].value); $.cookie("example", this[this.selectedIndex].value, {expires: 7});">
    <option value="0.png">1. Default</option>
    <option value="1.png">2. Collage</option>
    <option value="2.jpg">3. Darkness</option>
</select>
```

The cookie is not saving and Mozilla tells me `SyntaxError: syntax error`. How could I fix this problem?

I've included the jQuery file in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

How can I load the background once I saved the cookie? I have to call the `bg()` function but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try to keep your html and your javascript/jquery separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `on[event]` attributes. They're outdated and make maintenance harder. Instead attach your events in JS. Here's a jQuery example, using `$.cookie()`:

```
<select id="rds">
    <option value="0.png">1. Default</option>
    <option value="1.png">2. Collage</option>
    <option value="2.jpg">3. Darkness</option>
</select>
```

```
var setBackground = function(bgImg) {
    $.cookie('bgImg', bgImg);
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/' + bgImg + ')');
}

$(function() { 
    // on select change
    $('#rds').change(function() {
        setBackground($(this).val());
    });

    // on load
    setBackground($.cookie('bgImg'));
});
```

Comment: Very nice jquery example

Comment: To ensure that the setBackground function is not called before jQuery is loaded, you should do this: `$(function(){ setBackground($.cookie('bgImg')); });`

Comment: @Scalpweb good point, thanks. Added to the answer for clarity.

Comment: So I only have to paste that jQuery code and it will work? I have an error on mozilla that says "$.cookie is not a function"

Comment: Have you included the cookie plugin? It's not standard in jQuery. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Oh I didn't included the plugin, I didn't know that. Thank you. Also, the code you posted will change the background + save it into a cookie? Can I delete the old "bg()" function?

Comment: That's correct. You can delete `bg()` as it will no longer be used.

Comment: Last thing I have to ask: will that function overwtite datas? I mean: If I select the 'option 1' and later I click the 'option 3', which one will be saved?

Comment: The last one you click will be saved in the cookie, so in your scenario, `option 3` would be saved.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax error is here:

```
<select id="rds" onchange="bg(this[this.selectedIndex].value); $.cookie("example", this[this.selectedIndex].value, {expires: 7});">
```

You should write this:

```
<select id="rds" onchange="bg(this[this.selectedIndex].value); $.cookie('example', this[this.selectedIndex].value, {expires: 7});">
```

Note the simple quote around 'example'. On your example, you used double quotes that were interfering with the double quotes of the html attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax error is because you don't escape the quotes in the onchange event, change it to this:

```
<select id="rds" onchange="bg(this[this.selectedIndex].value); $.cookie('example', this[this.selectedIndex].value, {expires: 7});">
    <option value="0.png">1. Default</option>
    <option value="1.png">2. Collage</option>
    <option value="2.jpg">3. Darkness</option>
</select>
```

To load the background use the solution of the other answers :).